# Mumble-bot in java?

Tags: java, frameworks

I was having this idea to make a mumble bot like a IRC bot, type something in the chat and the bot replies, simple. But the bots I have made for IRC have all used some form of framework for connecting and handling the communication.

So my question is, is there a framework like pirc for mumble/murmur?